# truffle console does'nt return "undefined" when i use "await'

Tags: truffle, nft, ganache

I've been following a udemy course and supposedly after I make a variable for my contract with await, should get undefined but it's not doing that.

I tried revisiting my code files but i can't find anything wrong there. The exact line of code I'm talking about is

```
kryptoBird = await Kryptobird.deployed()
```

I expected undefined as a return statement but instead it returns a bunch of other information.

I've done this after migrating successfully and running the truffle compilation successfully. since i'm new to development, i have no idea what await does at all.

I'm doing this on Window's powershell and am not sure if that's the problem

Comment: Try the old fasion [`cmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) prompt to narrow down the problem. If the problem remains it is appearently not related to PowerShell (and you might remove the [tag:PowerShell] tag).

Comment: @iRon , yes i'm removing the powershell tag, did the same in cmd and the problem persists

Comment: why do u expect `undefined`